# POST and GET requests between Android and GAE

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I'm pretty well versed in Google App Engine (python) and have just started to learn Android App Development.

Is there a simple way to POST and GET data between my device and the GAE datastore?

I started reading about Endpoints, but it seems quite heavy (maybe I just need to increase my knowledge of Android and Java).

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm rather lost.

Comment: you only need HttpServlet in GAE and HttpPost in Android

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Endpoints are the easiest thing to implement communication between Android and Google App Engine app.

You can find a beginner video tutorial for Cloud Endpoints: [Developing Scalable Apps with Java with Google App Engine](https://www.udacity.com/course/ud859)

It's provided by Google employees and covers the most important things to learn.

Answer (score 0):

The way to talk remotely to a GAE Datastore (or search index), on Java or Python, is to use [Remote API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi). However, it is not clear that it will work from Android, [as discussed on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098679/unable-to-use-app-engine-remote-api-with-android-project). You could write a servlet that takes requests via POST or GET, and acts as a bridge to your datastore. But I worry about potential security issues offering a public endpoint to read and modify your apps internal data. You should authenticate carefully.